# Scala Pattern Matching Closures

Tags: scala, closures, akka, actor

I'm trying to pattern match a Closure. Is this possible? Using the syntax for declaring closures in functions, I specified the closure as `(call: => Unit)`

ie.
    `def foo = {
        case (call: => Unit) =>{1}
        case _ => 1}`

Comment: Consider also `PartialFunction`'s `isDefinedAt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `case (call: => Unit)`, try `case x: Function1[call, Unit]`.